# How come using an index isn't affecting my query length?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to grasp the concept of indexing. I'm using the Adventureworks2016 database in SQL Server. Adventureworks comes with the
`IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID` index in the `SalesOrderDetail` table
 and the
`IX_PurchaseOrderDetail_ProductID` index in the `PurchaseOrderDetail` table.

I ran the query below and it took 13 seconds on my computer.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [AdventureWorks2016].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] sod
 inner join  [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail] pod on sod.ProductID=pod.ProductID
```

I then removed both the `IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID` and the `IX_PurchaseOrderDetail_ProductID` indexes and it still took 13 seconds.

This is just one example. I've tried doing this with other tables, same thing happened. Why would the query take the same amount of time with the index as without it? I thought it was supposed to be quicker. Maybe someone can clear this up for me and possibly provide a query where I might see a noticable difference with and without the index.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should have a look at the explain plans of the queries.

Comment: Since you have no where predicate the index is only going to help a little bit here. It is likely an index scan on both tables because you are returning nearly the entire table in both cases. If you really want to gain an understanding of indexes and how they work I have not found a much series of articles than [this one](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-sql-server-indexes). it starts out simple and dives really deep by the end.

Comment: Thanks Sean for the article reference and explanation

Comment: We have online materials designed specifically to target the types of questions that you're asking. You'll find them here: <https://training.sqldownunder.com/p/sql-server-indexing-for-developers> They aren't free but they are low cost.

Comment: I haven't checked the adventure works schema but imagine that both of those indexes are leading column productid? If so then potentially they could do an efficient merge join but the problem is that you are selecting   `*` so the indexes won't cover the query, as a result they wont be used in that way as it would need to do lookups for every joined row from both tables

Comment: As already mentioned, the first step is to look at the query plan and see if the indexes are actually being used (no guarantee that they are). YOu aren't "using an index". You've created an index and you are assuming the index is being used.